Two injective paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ with the same curve can be expressed as $\gamma_1 = \gamma_2 \circ \alpha$ for some $\alpha$
My professor provided a proof to the following theorem that I am not quite able to understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I already spent a lot of time deciphering this (not very long) proof!

Theorem:

Let $\gamma_1: I \to X$ and $\gamma_2: J \to X$ be two injective paths into some metric space $(X, d)$ with the same curves i.e. $(\gamma_1) = (\gamma_2)$. Then there exists a bijective, continuous and monotone map $\alpha: I \to J$ s.t. $\gamma_1 = \gamma_2 \circ \alpha$.

His proof from the lecture notes:

Let $\alpha(t) = \gamma_2^{-1}(\gamma_1(t))$. This map is obviously bijective and monotone (if we can prove it is continuous) so we only have to proof that its continuous. Let $t \in I$, $\epsilon > 0$ and $s = \alpha(t)$. We want to show that $\alpha$ is continuous at $t$. Note that $A_2 = \gamma_2(\{\tau \in J: |t - s| \geq \epsilon\})$ is compact and
$$
d(\gamma_1(t), A_2) =: r > 0.
$$
Because $\gamma_1$ is continuous $\gamma_1^{-1}(B_r(\gamma(t)))$ is open and nonempty so there exists some $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\gamma_1(\tau) \in B_r(\gamma(t))$ if $|\tau - t| < \delta$. This implies continuity of $\alpha$.

My questions:

First of all I think when $A_2$ is defined it should say $|\tau - s| \geq \epsilon$ and not $|t - s| \geq \epsilon$ but this is just a typo?
Why is $\gamma_1^{-1}(B_r(\gamma(t)))$ sure to be nonempty? What is
$\gamma$? I think it should be $\gamma_1$?
Why can we find $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\gamma_1(\tau) \in B_r(\gamma(t))$ if $|\tau - t| < \delta$? What is $\tau$? How does
this suddenly imply the continuity of $\alpha$?
I am also confused that in the beginning we say some $\epsilon > 0$ is given but then proceed to never use $\epsilon$ again. What was it for? For my understanding we wanted to show that $|t - x| < \delta \Rightarrow d(\alpha(t), \alpha(x)) < \epsilon$ for all $x \in I$ and our fix $t$?

I would be equally happy if someone could refer me to another proof somewhere else that might be more readable. Many thanks in advance!

This is unnecessarily complicated. You should use instead the following: Suppose that $K$ is a compact topological space, $Y$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $f: K\to Y$ is a continuous injective map. Then $f^{-1}: f(K)\to K$ is also continuous.

@MoisheKohan Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately we have not yet introduced Hausdorff spaces and although we defined what a topological space is we do not at all work with the definition so I cannot really understand what you are suggesting or where this result you are referring to is coming from. But maybe I should look into this by myself...

Every metric space is Hausdorff. Do you know that for a subset $Z$ of a compact metric space $X$, $Z$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $Z$ is compact? Do you know that continuous image of a compact space is again compact? If you know, then prove that a continuous map of a compact metric space to another metric space sends closed subsets to closed  subsets. This will imply continuity of the inverse map that I mentioned before.

@MoisheKohan Thanks for the hint! I think I can answer both your questions with yes. We have shown these in the lecture. I guess I will try it this way.
